# Does the flattening operator matter when making dependent HTTP calls?

Tags: angular, rxjs

When making multiple dependent HTTP API calls using RxJS, the generally accepted answer is to use mergeMap() / flatMap() to chain the calls and end with one result stream. I'm wondering WHY mergeMap() is the go to operator of choice. Is this actually better or worse than any of the other 3 flattening operators? In my mind, you could use any of the four (merge, concat, switch, or exhaust) and end up with the same results/reliability.

In Angular, you may do a call such as:

```
function getCall(id) {
    return this.http.get<string>('http://www.apiurl.com/' + id);
}
```

This will only ever return one observable that will emit a string value. So doing something like

```
getCall(1).pipe(
    mergeMap(() => getCall(2))
).subscribe();
```

should behave exactly the same as

```
getCall(1).pipe(
    concatMap(() => getCall(2))
).subscribe();
```

since we can make the assumption that `getCall(id)` only ever returns ONE observable.

So does it actually make any difference which flattening operator someone uses in the context of an HTTP call.

Comment: Http calls are "one of" observables, so no, it doesn't matter. You should use the operator that would suit your needs if after some time you replace http with something like subject or a web socket connection or another "multi" observable, imho.

Comment: If the source observable and the dependent observable emit only once and then complete - as is the case for HTTP - the behaviours effected by `concatMap`, `switchMap` and `exhaustMap` will never be required. `mergeMap` - the simplest of the flattening operators - will suffice.